# How to render nested map from JSON in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, list, dictionary

I'm trying to render menu values from a JSON. Considering that this is a multilevel menu, I'm trying to do a nested map to render the full menu.

```
const menu = {
  data:[
  {
    title: "Home",
    child: [
      {
        title: "SubLevel1",
        child: {
          title: "SubSubLevel1"
        }
      },
      {
        title: "SubLevel2",
        child: [
          {title: "SubSubLevel1"},
          {title: "SubSubLevel2"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "About",
  },
  {
    title: "Contact",
  }
]}
```

And here is the part when I use the map function :

```
const MenuNavigation = () => {
    return (
        {menu.data.map((item) => ( 
            <div>
                <ul>{item.title}</ul> 
                {item.map((sub, id) =>
                    <li>{sub.child[id].title}</li>
                )} 
            </div>
        ))}
    )
};
```

I managed to render main level for the menu (Home, About, Contact), but how can I print sublevel & subsublevel values?

Another question: Is there a way to map recursively a tree structure?

Comment: Yes, you can render the menu recursively. But your menu does not have a consistent structure? If the `subChild` is replaced with `child` and `text` is replaced with `title` and `project` is replaced with `title`, then It is possible to do so. can you update the question like that then It is possible to give an answer only if possible.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I did as you asked, but don't you think it will create variables conflicts? Thanks for the help.

Comment: no conflicts will occur when you do it recursivly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

The `menu` should be like this. Your menu had one issue in child of "SubLevel1" not defined inside an array.

```
  const menu = {
    data: [
      {
        title: "Home",
        child: [
          {
            title: "SubLevel1",
            child: [{
              title: "SubSubLevel1",
            }],
          },
          {
            title: "SubLevel2",
            child: [{ title: "SubSubLevel1" }, { title: "SubSubLevel2" }],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "About",
      },
      {
        title: "Contact",
      },
    ],
  };
```

Render it recursively like below. I have added a margin-left to see the levels properly.

```
  const renderMenu = (menu) => {
    return menu.map((item) => (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: '25px' }}>
            {item.title}
            {item.child && renderMenu(item.child)}
        </div>
    ))
  }

  return <div>{renderMenu(menu.data)}</div>;
```

[image: Output]